# Images in portrait mode not displaying inside list view

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to display a fb like newsfeed inside my android app (one photo with a tagline). To do so, I have created the following code:

HomeFragment.java

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        newsFeedDescriptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.news_feed_description);
        newsFeedPics = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.news_feed_pics);

        newsFeedLayout = (RelativeLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.news_feed);
        newsFeedList=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_news_feed);

        newsFeedItems = new ArrayList<NewsFeedItem>();
        newsFeedItems.add(new NewsFeedItem(newsFeedDescriptions[0], newsFeedPics.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        newsFeedItems.add(new NewsFeedItem(newsFeedDescriptions[1], newsFeedPics.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        newsFeedItems.add(new NewsFeedItem(newsFeedDescriptions[2], newsFeedPics.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        newsFeedPics.recycle();
        newsFeedAdapter = new NewsFeedListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),newsFeedItems);
        newsFeedList.setAdapter(newsFeedAdapter);
        return rootView;
    }
```

Fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/news_feed"
    android:background="@color/theme_background">

   <ScrollView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="487dp" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_news_feed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/theme_background"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

NewsfeedListAdapter.java

```
package com.example.makemyday;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class NewsFeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   private Context context;
   private ArrayList<NewsFeedItem> newsFeedItems;

   public NewsFeedListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NewsFeedItem> newsFeedItems){
       this.context = context;
       this.newsFeedItems = newsFeedItems;
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       return newsFeedItems.size();
   }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int position) {       
       return newsFeedItems.get(position);
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
       return position;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       if (convertView == null) {
           LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                   context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.newsfeed_item, null);
       }

       ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.newsfeed_image);
       TextView description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.newsfeed_description);

       img.setImageResource(newsFeedItems.get(position).getImage());        
       description.setText(newsFeedItems.get(position).getDescription());

       // displaying count
       // check whether it set visible or not

       return convertView;
   }
}
```

NewsfeedItem.java

```
public class NewsFeedItem {

    private String description;
    private int image;

    public NewsFeedItem(){}

    public NewsFeedItem(String description, int image){
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getDescription(){
        return this.description;
    }

    public int getImage(){
        return this.image;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description){
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setImage(int image){
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

newsfeed_rectangle.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
         <gradient
            android:endColor="@color/theme_foreground"
            android:centerColor="@color/theme_foreground"
            android:startColor="@color/theme_foreground"
            android:angle="270" />
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
```

newsfeeditem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@drawable/newsfeed_rectangle">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/newsfeed_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newsfeed_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/newsfeed_image"
        android:minHeight="12dp"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Only the photos in landscape show properly, but not the photos taken in potrait mode.. I dont understand why

Comment: post your `newsfeed_item`

Comment: it's posted already above

Comment: `newsfeed_item.xml` your listview row file, i don't think that you have upload that one. check it once again

Comment: i added it in the edits

Comment: android:layout_width="match_parent" replace "wrap_content" & set scaleType="fitxy" try this but make sure your image should in some fix size

Comment: I did that.. I still cannot see the images that were taken in portrait mode

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44127/discussion-between-chintan-khetiya-and-ankita)

Comment: @Ankita Can you post the screenshot of your layout? Do not put the `ListView` inside `ScrollView`. Its bad logic.

Comment: I removed scrollview..

Comment: @Ankita Make your `ListView` height to `fill_parent` `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

Comment: @GrIsHu, I used chintan khetiya's advice and added minheight maxheight parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because of your image view.  You are using for your imageview but you haven't set your min - max Height - Width.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

So, In that case first image could be large or second image could be small and so on.. and will that spread in your view as you have set "match_parent".

Try this,

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/newsfeed_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:minHeight="120dp" // set your value as per your requirement 
        android:minWidth="180dp"  // set your value as per your requirement 
        android:maxWidth="420dp"  // set your value as per your requirement 
        android:maxHeight="680dp"  // set your value as per your requirement 
        android:scaleType="fitXY" // to set image in fix X..Y points 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

Hope this works for you.